# Force Bash-Script to wait for a Perl-Script that awaits input

Tags: bash, perl, user-input

I'm having a Bash-Script that sequentially runs some Perl-Scripts which are read from a file. These scripts require the press of Enter to continue.

Strangely when I run the script it's never waiting for the input but just continues. I assume something in the Bash-Script is interpreted as an Enter or some other Key-Press and makes the Perl continue.

I'm sure there is a solution out there but don't really know what to look for.

My Bash has this while-Loop which iterates through the list of Perl-Scripts (which is listed in `seqfile`)

```
while read zeile; do
    if [[ ${datei:0:1} -ne 'p' ]]; then
        datei=${zeile:8}
    else
        datei=$zeile
    fi
    case ${zeile: -3} in
    ".pl")
    perl  $datei  #Here it just goes on...
    #echo "Test 1"
    #echo "Test 2"
    ;;
    ".pm")
        echo $datei "is a Perl Module" 
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Something elso"
    ;;
    esac
done <<< $seqfile;
```

You notice the two commented lines With `echo "Test 1/2"`. I wanted to know how they are displayed.
Actually they are written under each other like there was an Enter-Press:

```
Test 1
Test 2
```

The output of the Perl-Scripts is correct I just have to figure out a way how to force the input to be read from the user and not from the script.

Comment: what happens is perl script is executed on command line. Does it return the prompt immediately?

Comment: Print the value of $datei to make sure is what you want.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz - if the script is executed on the command line it works as it's supposed to be (after executing various Perl-Scripts several times with the same command I decided to do some automation). Actually, the Bash-Script works - it just _jumps over_ the input I want to give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the perl script redirect input from `/dev/tty`.

Proof of concept:

```
while read line ; do
    export line
    perl -e 'print "Enter $ENV{line}: ";$y=<STDIN>;print "$ENV{line} is $y\n"' </dev/tty
done <<EOF
foo
bar
EOF
```

Program output (user input in **bold**):

`Enter foo: 123
foo is 123

Enter bar: 456
bar is 456`

Comment: I had to re-write it a little, but basically just change the one line to `perl $zeile </dev/tty` . I don't want it to wait for every single input (sometimes no input is required at all). I see your knowledge of bash is bigger than mine, would you mind explaining also why you use the `-e` Parameter and export the line before instead of just using it directly? (Upvoted and Marked as answer already, but some explanation would be nice, thank you)

Comment: The `-e` and the `export` probably aren't relevant to your specific problem. `-e` instructs perl to treat the next command line argument as perl code to execute rather than a file containing Perl code. `export` makes the bash variable `$line` available in the Perl process so I could output it.

Answer (score 3):

@mob's answer is interesting, but I'd like to propose an alternative solution for your use case that will **also work if your overall bash script is run with a specific input redirection** (i.e. not `/dev/tty`).

Minimal working example:

- script.perl

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env perl
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  {
      local( $| ) = ( 1 );
      print "Press ENTER to continue: ";
      my $resp = <STDIN>;
  }
  print "OK\n";
  ```
- script.bash

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  exec 3>&0 # backup STDIN to fd 3

  while read line; do
      echo "$line"
      perl "script.perl" <&3 # redirect fd 3 to perl's input
  done <<EOF
  First
  Second
  EOF

  exec 3>&- # close fd 3
  ```

So this will work with both: `./script.bash` in a terminal and `yes | ./script.bash` for example...

For more info on redirections, see e.g. [this article](https://www.refining-linux.org/archives/30-23-File-descriptors.html) or [this cheat sheet](http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf).

Hoping this helps

Comment: You were just 8 seconds too late I'm afraid but I find your answer interesting and your links helpful (upvote!), yet I can't make your solution work :/
`bash: [[: /: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/")
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor`

Comment: @Qohelet I cannot reproduce your error. Did you copy the script.bash file as is, and run `chmod a+x script.bash && ./script.bash` ? If yes, can you give more hints about your config (such as the OS and the shell)? Do you have the same error if you run `exec 3>&0` in your terminal?

Comment: You may also want to run `ls -l /dev/fd/` in a terminal to get the list of opened file descriptors

Comment: Overlooked your `exec 3>&0` and didn't put it in my code :/ - your idea works perfectly fine.