# Read after 'while read lines' not evaluated (SHELL)

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am currently trying to debug some scripts I've made and I cannot find a way for a 'read' instruction to be executed.

To summarize, I've got two functions, one with a 'while read lines' that is called after a pipe, and another functions that read user input after while read is processed.

Let me now explain this with code :

- This is how I called my function ($lines contains multiple lines separated with '\n')

echo "$lines" | saveLines

```
saveLines(){
  # ...
  while read line ; do
    # processing lines
  done
  myOtherFunction
}

myOtherFunction(){
  echo "I am here !" # <= This is printed in console
  read -p "Type in : " tmp  # <= Input is never asked to user, and the message is not printed
  echo "I now am here !" # <= This is printed in console
}
```

This code is simplified but the spirit is here.
I tried to insert a 'read' instruction before the 'read -p ...', it did not seems to change things...

So please, if you can show my error or tell me why this behavior is expected, I would be very happy. Thanks for you time

Comment: The loop needs some way to exit early, before it has consumed the entire input to `saveLines` before `myOtherFunction` gets called. Alternatively, you may want `myOtherFunction` to read directly from `/dev/tty`, or at least from a file descriptor other than standard input.

Comment: Note that the `read` *is* being executed; it just has a non-zero exit status because there is nothing left to read (and it appears that `read` detects this before it tries to display the prompt).

Comment: @chepner I've got code in my while loop (some processing and writing in files), and '$lines' is a finite amount of lines. Did you mean I need to add an extra line at the end of '$lines' and add a 'if [...] then break;' in my loop ?

Comment: Could you try `read -p "Type in : " tmp < /dev/tty` instead? (the issue certainly comes from the fact that you run the command `echo "$lines" | saveLines` so that when myOtherFunction is executed, the standard input is not the tty anymore)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force Bash-Script to wait for a Perl-Script that awaits input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669657/force-bash-script-to-wait-for-a-perl-script-that-awaits-input)

Comment: @ErikMD I don't want to redirect saveLines to myOtherFunction, or I perhaps misunderstood the point of the answer

Comment: @floxcc Probably two extra lines: one to act as the sentinel for the `if` statement to detect, and one for `myOtherFunction` to read once it gets called.

Comment: @ErikMD Ho I see what you mean in your edit, and yes it does work. Can you answer, and I validate this solution ? (the < /dev/tty solution)
I was thinking it will work on unix system but not in git-bash, but it works on either, thanks

Comment: @floxcc OK, glad that it worked for you.

Comment: @ErikMD Just in case, is this a bad pratice what I attend to achieve ? Is it a proper solution to read input before calling saveLines and pass it through as an extra line ?

Comment: @floxcc yes maybe you should avoid this intermediate step of variable $lines. Also note that `echo "$var"` is bad practice by itself, if need be one should use `printf` with appropriate arguments to display the content of a variable.

Comment: If "$lines" comes from a file you could just do `saveLines <"$file"`. But if the lines are built programmatically in Bash, I'd suggest dropping the `while read`, and use a Bash array `"${elements[@]}"`...

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer, will rework that and take a better look at arrays. Never realy used them so I guess it's time

Comment: @floxcc you're welcome! BTW you might be interested in looking at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ (a very good reference about Bash and shell scripting)

Comment: @ErikMD thanks. Nice blog you got, really good article on arrays, didn't look all the others, but it's bookmarked for later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very close to [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669657/force-bash-script-to-wait-for-a-perl-script-that-awaits-input), in a slightly different context. To be more precise and as explained by the OP, the command run was

```
echo "$lines" | saveLines
```

meaning that the standard input of the code executed by saveLines wasn't the terminal anymore, but the same descriptor as the standard output of the `echo...` command.

To solve this it thus suffices to replace

```
…
read -p "Type in : " tmp
…
```

with

```
…
read -p "Type in : " tmp </dev/tty
…
```